Android Jetpack Compose TV Focus restoring with navigation
I have a two screens on my sample app : HomeScreen and DetailsScreen.
On the HomeScreen I've a LazyVerticalGrid of 100 elements and the DetailsScreen is just a back button.
When scroll on the HomeScreen, enter in the DetailsScreen and go back, the focus is not restored on the pressed card.
Here's the full code of my sample app :
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = "Home"
            ) {
                composable("Home") {
                    val list = rememberSaveable { List(100) { "Card $it" } }
                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 70.dp),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 40.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
                    ) {
                        itemsIndexed(
                            items = list,
                            key = { index, _ -> index }
                        ) { _, item ->
                            var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .onFocusChanged { isFocused = it.hasFocus }
                                    .size(height = 70.dp, width = 70.dp)
                                    .background(Color.Red)
                                    .border(width = 2.dp, color = if (isFocused) Color.White else Color.Transparent)
                                    .clickable { navController.navigate("Details") }
                                    .focusable(),
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {
                                Text(text = item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                composable("Details") {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Button(
                            onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Go back")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Is there a simple way to implement the focus restoration (without setting a focus restorer to all cards) ?

How about var isFocused by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }?

The problem is your code does not save focused position during navigation, try this fix with rememberSaveable.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = "Home"
            ) {
                composable("Home") {
                    val list = rememberSaveable { List(100) { "Card $it" } }
                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 70.dp),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 40.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
                    ) {
                        itemsIndexed(
                            items = list,
                            key = { index, _ -> index }
                        ) { _, item ->
                            var isFocused by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .onFocusChanged { isFocused = it.hasFocus }
                                    .size(height = 70.dp, width = 70.dp)
                                    .background(Color.Red)
                                    .border(width = 2.dp, color = if (isFocused) Color.White else Color.Transparent)
                                    .clickable { navController.navigate("Details") }
                                    .focusable(),
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {
                                Text(text = item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                composable("Details") {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Button(
                            onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Go back")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I've tried and it doesn't work. The focus is still restored on another card when navigating back.

@CorentinZuber Okay then, add val focusedIndex = rememberSaveable {mutableIntState(0)} under val navController = rememberNavController() and change it on focus change, moving state outside composable("Home") should help to survive navigation
